# Setting data.table entries

Tags: r, join, data.table, key

I have a data.table for which I am trying to set certain elements.

```
mydt <- as.data.table(data.frame(a=letters[1:26],b=c(1:26)))
setkey(mydt, a)
```

I can see that I can filter the entries using the key values.

```
> mydt[c('b','f','g'),b]
[1] 2 6 7
> mydt[c('b','f','g')]$b
[1] 2 6 7
```

However, when I try to set some values in the `b` column, I get:

```
> mydt[c('b','f','g')]$b = c(45,67,89)
Error in `[.data.table`(`*tmp*`, c("b", "f", "g")) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
> mydt[c('b','f','g'),b] = c(45,67,89)
Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

The error messages seem cryptic to me.

Comment: When using `data.table` you should update / add columns using `:=`. Did you look at the introductory tutorial?

Comment: On my computer (data.table 1.10.5, r 3.3.3), I get a warning, not an error. My guess is that you somehow broke your key before running that command. And with `mydt[c('b','f','g')]$b = c(45L, 67L, 89L)`, I get no message at all.

Comment: `data.table`'s author is advocating people no longer rely on keys in their code.  Slip-ups like this can happen, and even when it's guaranteed to work, it's not always clear to a reader which columns are keyed.  Use the `on =` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `:=`

```
mydt[c('b','f','g'), b := c(45L,67L,89L)]
```

Make sure that the column types are matched as `c(45, 67, 89)` is `numeric` while the `b` class is `integer`.  One option is to add `L` as suffix or use `as.integer(c(45, 67, 89))`